# UE4 gets stuck at 75% when using ConstructorHelpers

Tags: c++, crash, unreal-engine4

UE4 gets stuck when opening if I use this code but it opens fine if I disable it.

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UBehaviorTree> BT(TEXT("BehaviorTree'/Game/Blueprints/Turret_BT.Turret_BT'"));
```

It also runs fine if I compile it after opening the editor.

My header:

```
 #pragma once
 #include "CoreMinimal.h"
 #include "AIController.h"
 #include "Perception/AIPerceptionComponent.h"
 #include "TurretController.generated.h"

 UCLASS()
 class CPPPROJECT1_API ATurretController : public AAIController
 {
     GENERATED_BODY()
 
 public:
     ATurretController();
     virtual void BeginPlay() override;
 
     UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, VisibleAnywhere)
         UAIPerceptionComponent* PerceptionComp;
 
     UFUNCTION()
         virtual void OnTargetPerceptionUpdated(AActor* Actor, FAIStimulus Stimulus);
 };
```

My .cpp:

```
 #include "TurretController.h"
 #include "BehaviorTree/BehaviorTree.h"
 
 ATurretController::ATurretController() {
     PerceptionComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<UAIPerceptionComponent>(FName("AIPerceptionComponent"));
     PerceptionComp->OnTargetPerceptionUpdated.AddDynamic(this, &ATurretController::OnTargetPerceptionUpdated);
     
     static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UBehaviorTree> BT(TEXT("BehaviorTree'/Game/Blueprints/Turret_BT.Turret_BT'"));
 
 }
 
 void ATurretController::BeginPlay() {
     Super::BeginPlay();
 
 }
 
 void ATurretController::OnTargetPerceptionUpdated(AActor* Actor, FAIStimulus Stimulus) {
 
 }
```

I got the reference to the object from the editor and it works fine with other objects.

Comment: What is it declared as `static`?

Comment: ConstructorHelpers structure is used to get a reference to the object/assets from the game. Sorry, I took so long to reply.

Comment: Where is that structure used in your code? In your constructor you create a variable `BT` but don't use it anywhere. Also, since `BT` is declared inside the constructor, its scope is restricted in the constructor - other functions may not be able to access it.

Comment: Yeah I use it only inside the constructor but since it's not working, I removed the code that uses this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, there was no problem with the code. The problem was with the content inside of the BehaviorTree.